# I'm trying to run video by making a video player app with simplified controls, and having issue with findViewById

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

> The full error message I'm getting is this: Not enough information to infer type variable T

```
import android.net.Uri
import android.net.Uri.*
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.MediaController
import android.widget.VideoView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        //Find the VideoView class by its id
        val videoView = findViewById(R.id.testView)
        //Creating MediaController
        val mediaController = MediaController(this)
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView)
        //specify the location of media file
        val uri:Uri = parse(
            "android.resource://" + packageName
                    + "/raw/test"
        )
        //Setting MediaController and URI, then starting the videoView
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController)
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
        videoView.requestFocus()
        videoView.start()
    }

}
```

> Full error message i'm getting :
> Not enough information to infer type variable T

Comment: change to `val videoView:VideoView = findViewById(R.id.testView)`

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin isn’t able to definitively determine what class the `findViewById` is trying to find, so you will need to define it yourself. Try updating your code to this, to specify that the item is a `VideoView` object:

```
val videoView = findViewById(R.id.testView) as VideoView
```